# How to use the values of a dataframe as a column and put values in them selectively?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm new to use pandas data frame and I'm actually stuck with a problem.

I have a main dictionary, which is basically a dataframe in the code, which looks like this:

```
A      B      ATTR      VAL
AA     BB     type      circular
AA     BB     size      2mm
AA     BB     shape     square
AA     BB     tip       bend
```

I'll provide a string that will check this dataframe and pick the words and return an output that will look pretty much like this:

```
A     B     type       size   shape   tip
AA    BB    circular   2mm    square  bend
```

This I will do for a huge set of data, But right now I'm trying it out on this, once done I will apply the same code on that huge dataset.

```
main_dict = pd.read_excel('File.xlsx')
header = main_dict.iloc[:,0:2]
data = main_dict.iloc[:,2:4]
matr_desc = "AA BB  2mm circular bend".split()

for i,j in enumerate(main_dict['Attribute']):
  for k,l in enumerate(main_dict['Values']):
    print(l)
    header[j][k] = l
```

After this I am getting stuck, I know this might be very easy but since I am new I'm having a bit of difficulty constructing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
df.set_index(['A','B', 'ATTR']).unstack('ATTR')
```

or [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
df.pivot_table(index=['A', 'B'], columns='VAL', values='ATTR', aggfunc='first')
```

Both will produce the expected output. However, note that duplicates spanning the `A`, `B` and `ATTR` columns (i.e. multiple rows where these three columns all have the same values) could have unwanted results.